# What is the best of giving Azure Logic app to Production team

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am new to this Logic apps.
I have logic apps configured in my dev azure subscriptions. What is the best way to provide the LogicApp to other team like Production team etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout the LogicApp documentation on automation, ARM templates & VS tooling
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-create-deploy-template

Small answer will be you should be having ARM templates for the logic app creation which are parameterized with the environment information & necessary dependencies. So what you share are the ARM templates & steps to execute them.

You can also develop ARM templates for logic apps using VS2015
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-deploy-from-vs